# Python regex doesn't work as I expected

Tags: python, regex

Why doesn't this work?!

```
re.match(r".*hello.*", "\n\nhello\n\n", re.MULTILINE)
```

Help please?

Windows 7 x64
Python 2.7.3

Comment: What do you want it to match?

Comment: I'm trying to match the "hello" - it's a simplistic example of what I'm really trying to do (match text on a single line inside of a text file without iterating over every line)

Comment: The fact you are running this on Windows is irrelevant for this question. There are differences when dealing with the filesystem, where if one does use the `\` directory separator there are differences to other environments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S) instead:

```
re.match(r".*hello.*", "\n\nhello\n\n", re.DOTALL)
```

Quoting the documentation:

> Make the `'.'` special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, `'.'` will match anything except a newline.

`re.MULTILINE` alters where `^` and `$` match, not what the `.` dot pattern matches.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was going to propose that OP try.